# Why CSS Animation(webkit-animation) is not working?

Tags: html, css, animation

I wrote the code like below

```css
/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="banner-img" src="https://www.seoultech.ac.kr/storage/banner/rolling/SNUST1615422266317.png">
    <div class="text">Caption One</div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="banner-img" src="https://www.seoultech.ac.kr/storage/banner/rolling/SNUST1552549610052.jpg">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="banner-img" src="http://bnx.oa.gg/img/bnx_16fw_visual_03_list.jpg">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>
```

But it does not work
and I realized that the first and second line in .fade tag in CSS is showed as cancel line on my web page.

How can I fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Seems to work fine. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gOmRaYQ

Comment: I already know that. But it is not applied on my web page.. :( might the structure of my web page be a problem?

Comment: You have to demonstrate the issue **in the question**. If you can't do that we can't help.

Comment: I rarely use this site so i was not used to asking. But i solve this problem. I omit 'defer' keyword at script tag in html. Thank you for your help.